# Update component styles dynamically from state on initial load?

Tags: reactjs

My app has theme variations that are stored in a database that id like to update many elements on initial render only, but have it carried over to every view. It seems it would make sense to update the top level app container components style with state, but this seems to produce an endless loop. Is there something im doing wrong or is there a easier way to achieve this? I do not want to use inline styles, or run these styles to 50 components across the app.

example of what im trying currently with one style:

```
const StyledApp = styled.div`
  body .pagination a { background-color: ${this.state.color}}
`;

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { color:"" };
autoBind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.setColorState()
}

setColorState() {
  var color = //get color from db
  this.setState({ color:color});
}

render() {
  const { props, state, setAfterLoginPath } = this;
    return (
     <StyledApp ready={this.state.ready} loading={props.loading}>
       //app code
     </StyledApp>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: I think `setState` should be called `setColorState`, looks like you got it other way around.

Comment: youre right, i updated it for continuity. just example code though

Comment: you need to change `setColorState` to `setState` inside of it as well.

Comment: right again, updated. any idea how to achieve what im trying to do though?

Comment: Not sure what `autoBind` does, but it seems that nothing on the code you posted should generate an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, the code as it is should work correctly, the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Youre implying you can update the component styles via state like im trying to do?

Comment: setColorState missing (), also stuff in //app code might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can do something like styled components doc says passing props to style

```
    const StyledApp = styled.div`
body .pagination a { background-color: ${props=>props.color}} 





<StyledApp ready={this.state.ready} loading={props.loading} color={this.state.color}>
//app code
</StyledApp>
```

Comment: This works thank you! i had to remove the body area as the app container resides within the body of course though